# Can very dilute acids exposed to air become more concentrated as water evaporates?

Tags: acid-base, safety, concentration

If a very minute quantity spilled acid (e.g. $\ce{H2SO4}$, though the question would apply to other acids as well) is cleaned up with water (e.g. yielding a $0.0001~\mathrm{M}$ solution), and some of the water (dilute acid solution) is left behind, will the resulting solution become more concentrated as the water evaporates?  Would there be any danger that a drop of an initially-harmless concentration might become a visually-unnoticeable quantity of acid that was strong enough to pose a contact hazard?  Would wiping an area down with a moderately-dilute solution of a weak base such as sodium bicarbonate be an appropriate safety precaution, or would it be unnecessary if any acid droplets that might exist on a surface have been thoroughly diluted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sulfuric acid (and other acids) can be concentrated through evaporation of water.  It would be a good idea to wash the surface down with dilute, basic solution.  That said, if I'm reading your post correctly, your droplets are already 0.1M.  That is still a strong acid and care should be taken in its clean up.  I was once working with a 0.01M solution of sulfuric acid and when cleaning the flask a few drops of the dilute solution splattered onto my foot, I didn't even notice it at the time.  An hour or so later my foot started to burn.  When I looked, my sock was gone in the affected area.  If you're dealing with anything more than drop or two use a spill kit and let someone know what you are doing.

Comment: Yeah, I probably meant something more like 0.001M or maybe 0.00001M [it's been ages since I've taken chemistry].  Basically, the question is not so much about a spilled quantity which is large enough to be visible, but rather the possibility that wiping down a surface where acid was handled, and were it would be possible that a drop might have fallen without being noticed, might end up leaving behind a highly-concentrated residue.

Comment: Yes, if anything is left behind it will re-concentrate.  A mild base wash would make good sense.

Comment: That's what I figured, but I would have expected that if re-concentration was a hazard the instructions that came with the battery and acid for my sump pump would have suggest that as a reason for why use of baking soda was a good idea.

Comment: "If you aren't in a hurry, you can concentrate sulfuric acid by allowing the water to evaporate naturally. This takes several days."  http://chemistry.about.com/od/makechemicalsyourself/a/How-To-Make-Sulfuric-Acid-At-Home.htm

Comment: Is there any minimum quantity or concentration below which one wouldn't have to worry?  If a drop were placed in a bathtub full of distilled water and left alone long enough for the water to evaporate, could that drop still pose a hazard?

Comment: Tap water, depending where it comes from, can have a pH between about 6.5-8.5 due to dissolved minerals and gases.  I suspect the long-term risk is low given all the stuff in the air for it to react with as well.

Comment: Is there any general principle for what quantities and concentrations are worth worrying about, if one wants to err on the side of caution but not paranoia?

Comment: See  https://www.phys.unsw.edu.au/safety/documents/SOP_acid_spill.pdf  as far as I'm aware they're all handled the same unless it's a large spill (~1 liter).  If any of this has been helpful, please mark the answer as accepted, thanks.

Comment: I've marked the answer as accepted.  Do you have any thoughts about whether things like whether the possibility of re-concentration is sufficient that lead acid battery instructions should mention it?

Comment: Instructions can only go so far.  Rather than mentioning re-concentration, I'd focus the instructions on the seriousness of all acid spills and the need for **complete** cleanup and proper disposal of waste.

Comment: Applying the stated level of protocol to a single drop that falls from the hose while moving from one opening to the next would seem excessive.  I would expect that wiping down a single-drop spill with a disposable rag that's damp with a solution of NaHCO3 would suffice, but the baking soda should not be considered optional.  Would that seem an appropriate level of care?  Suggesting a protocol that might seem excessive for single-drop quantities leaves unclear what level of care is required for such quantities.

Comment: I agree, even for a few drops.  The only additional thing I would do if the drop was on an easily accessible, flat surface would be to first put a little bicarbonate powder on the drop(s), let it sit for a minute or two and then wipe it up with a damp (bicarbonate solution), disposable rag.